# Is there any way to access the name of a grunt task via the template engine?

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to gain access to task name via the template engine.

If I run `grunt my-task:my-sub-task`, I would like to be able to grab the string `my-task:my-sub-task` (or better yet just `my-sub-task`), via something like `<%= grunt.currentTask %>` within the task configuration.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can access it via `grunt.cli.tasks`

You can add a config variable to access it with teplate syntax if needed

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answer, `grunt.cli.tasks` works in getting the full task name.

It might be preferable to get the “my-sub-task” part, like in your case. You can use [`grunt.task.current.args`](https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks#this.args) for this.

Here is an example task that names the destination files using the subtask name.

```js
plugin: {
  webp: {
    expand: true,
    src: ["input/*"],
    dest: "output",
    ext: ".<%= grunt.task.current.args %>.webp",
    flatten: true,
    # task details
  }
},
```

This configures only the task `plugin:webp` but it expects a subtask to run. The subtask name determines the extension of the destination files. For example, when `plugin:webp:4x` is run, it will generate `output/file.4x.webp`.